Custom Audit File results in error: Nessus has not identified that the chosen audit applies to the target device
I have created downloaded an Audit File from Tenable for Palo Alto Firewall v9 and v10. I edited the benchmark to remove the benchmarks not listed in my checklist. So for example 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.3. So i removed 1.1.1.2 from the audit file.
I used compliance scan as well as advanced scan to scan my palo device. Then received this error: NOTE: Nessus has not identified that the chosen audit applies to the target device.
Any idea what is causing it and also how I can make this work out. I also tried the nessus default compliance audit file and still the same error.
